# How do you get the dialoge to pay the crime bounty off?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I committed a crime, and found out no matter what I do, I don't have the option to pay of my crime bounty. I even tried in all holds, but it did not work.

Any way to fix this? I have the mod *Crime Overhaul* installed

Comment: If you open your crime statistics page, what does it say? Hit `esc`, and one of the menus lists crimes. I don’t remember the name of the tab it’s under. It should say what your bounty amount is in each hold. If nobody witnessed your crime, you wouldn’t have gained a bounty.

Comment: I have 2000 gold bounty in every hold.

Comment: Do the guards ever ask you to come quietly or face the Jarl’s justice? What if you sheath your weapons a couple times when they’re attacking you?

Comment: I can open the dialoge but never get the option that alows you to pay off your crime i only get the options I submit. take me to jail. and I'd rather die than go to prison.

Answer (score 2):

Your mod has this in their readme:

> MURDER
>
> A new variable has been added - CrimeViolentPayThreshold - which
>   determines the amount of violent crime you can accumulate before
>   paying fines is no longer an option. The default is 1200, the same as
>   murder.

[Source](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71531/?)

Comment: I know I have 200 gold violent crime gold not over 1200

Comment: @Raiin You said 2000 above.

Comment: the rest of the crimes are small ones not violent crimes crimes like stealing pickpocketing

Comment: Does the mod actually show you the two different values?  Maybe it's a bug with the mod.

Comment: no the mod dose not show it iI know it because i did the same crimes in every hold

Comment: So you're telling me you were able to rack up 2000 gold worth of petty crimes without getting arrested, killing a guard or getting killed?

Comment: yes I did these are the crimes i did Became a warewolf (1500) assault (200) stealing a horse (450) so i dont have exatly 2000 gold bounty but its close. the warewolf is not real but it represents the items I stole.

Comment: Gaining more crime gold fixed my problem. I guess 2135 gold has a bug so that  you cant pay it off.

Comment: @Raiin, that is a very particular bug. You should post a self-answer explaining what happened to fix your issue, and accept it when you can, so other users that run into your problem try the solution.